# Jquery won't load content into the DIV area .. where did I go wrong

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-load

Ok , so I am trying to load content from a another page using JQUERY LOAD method SO THE content can appear without the page refreshing ... I did that but when I click on the link , it still redirects me to the other page instead of the content loading into the div.

Below is my code ..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title> MadScore, A Social Scoring Platform </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/madscore.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skins/tango/skin.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1, buttonNextHTML:"<div></div>", buttonPrevHTML:"<div></div>"
    });
});
</script>


//Here is where I made the Jquery call for the div below with class "panel" but it won't load ..

<scrip type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("profile").click(function(){
    $(".panel").load("this.href");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="sliding-panel">
<div class="container">
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<li>

<li>
<div class="panel"> //panel supposed to be triggered by Jquery
<h1> People </h1>
<?php
 database_connect();
$query = "select * from People";
$result = $connection->query($query);
$row_count =$result->num_rows;

for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++)
  {
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=".$row['ID']."' id='profile'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>";

  }


?>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tag should be `<script type="text/javascript></script>`

Comment: Why do you include TWO different versions of jQuery?! I'm pretty sure they won't expand each other...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `#` while binding click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#profile").click(function(){  // add # here
    $(".panel").load("this.href");
  });
});
```

Also use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event to dynamically added elements.

Comment: How exactly ?  I am not sure I understand what you mean .. I added the # for profile but it's still not loading in the div ???

Comment: @user1787184: First check if click event is triggered or not by adding alert.

Answer (score 0):

First, your selector is missing `#`. Also, you are just passing a string to the load method: `"this.href"`, you need to pass the actual link: `$this.attr('href')`

Regarding the issue with the link, you need to **prevent the default action** (which is the the click on `a`). For that you have two options:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
    alert('on ready works!');
      $("#profile").click(function(event){
        $(".panel").load($this.attr('href'), function(){
          alert('ajax called finished');
        });             
        return false; // or event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: so should I use return false ?? and add the  # sign ?  I am not sure I understand cancel the click on a event

Comment: @user1787184 you need the # sign just like I put it in the code above so you can correctly select the element a. Now after you click a link you are redirected so you need to cancel the default action (which is the click on the link so you are not redirected). I've updated my answer so show an alternative method

Comment: thanks for helping but I am still redirected to the page after clicking on the link .. I copied and pasted this <scrip type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#profile").click(function(event){
        $(".panel").load("this.href");
         event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    </script>

Comment: is the event even executing? use $(function (){} ); instead. See updated code. Do you use firebug btw? putting a breakpoint will save you time.

Comment: @user1787184 the first option has a few alerts. That'll put you in the right path.

Comment: @Ulises.. As soon as I load my website , the alert comes up .. and it says on ready works !  what I actually wanted is that when the link in the div already is clicked on , the content of that page it is linked to appears in the div ..without having to refresh the page .. Only on ready works shows up .. not on click !

Comment: @Ulises.. On click works alert shows up .. so what should that exactly mean ?  I never worked with Jquery before .. Only PHP and MYSQL .. a little more hints would be much appreciated ..

Comment: @user1787184 which alert? I put two in the code, depending on which fire will tell you which event is being handled. Maybe both show up.

Comment: Both alerts work actually .. first when I land on the page , alert on ready works .. then when I click on the first link , on CLICK ALERT works ... what would that mean ?

Comment: @user1787184 it means the ajax called should have been fired. I have updated the code once again since the way it was getting href was wrong, it was just a string.

Comment: On clicking the link .. it still takes me back to the other page I don't know why ..