# jQuery Load isn't loading content into the div, redirects to the other page.

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Ok , so I am trying to load content from a another page using JQUERY LOAD method SO THE content can appear without the page refreshing. I did that but when I click on the link below generated from PHP , it still redirects me to the other page instead of the content loading into the `<div class="panel">`

Below is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title> MadScore, A Social Scoring Platform </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/madscore.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skins/tango/skin.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1, buttonNextHTML:"<div></div>", buttonPrevHTML:"<div></div>"
    });
});
</script>


//Here is where I made the Jquery call for the div below with class "panel" but it won't load ..

<scrip type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("profile").click(function(){
    $(".panel").load("this.href");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="sliding-panel">
<div class="container">
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<li>

<li>
<div class="panel"> //panel supposed to be triggered by Jquery
<h1> People </h1>
<?php
 database_connect();
$query = "select * from People";
$result = $connection->query($query);
$row_count =$result->num_rows;

for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++)
  {
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=".$row['ID']."' id='profile'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>";

  }


?>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="panel">
<h1>Ballers</h1>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="panel">
<h1>Movies</h1>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="panel">
<h1> Talking heads</h1>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You already asked the exact same question. If you don't receive the help you need you should work on your question or address specifics in the responses given in the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966753/jquery-wont-load-content-into-the-div-area-where-did-i-go-wrong

Answer (score 1):

There are few errors,

```
1 Wrong spelling of script. scrip should be script
2 wrong syntax of id selector.  $("profile") should be  $("#profile")
3 loading constant string instread of current element href. load("this.href") should be 
  load(this.href)
```

Change

```
<scrip type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("profile").click(function(){
    $(".panel").load("this.href");
  });
});
</script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#profile").click(function(){
    $(".panel").load(this.href);
  });
});
</script>
```